# Php parse JSON subarray

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON String in PHP:

```
$casedata = "{\"id\":4823,\"status\":2,\"steps\":12,\"error\":\"catched error playing testcase\",\"result\":\"\",\"sublog\":[{\"step\":8,\"message\":\"corpus.invalidState.2.getBlockedRegionsForUnit\"},{\"step\":10,\"message\":\"corpus.invalidState.2.getBlockedRegionsForUnit\"}]}";
```

I try to parse this with

```
$array = json_decode($casedata,true);
```

No I walk through the keys with:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo "Array";
        }else{
            echo "Content: ".$key." / ".$value." <br/>";
        }
}
```

The output is

```
Content: id / 4823
Content: status / 2
Content: steps / 12
Content: error / catched error playing testcase 
Content: result /
Array
```

Works fine. But how to get the $key and $value out of the sub array "sublog"? I tried as sample with:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo "Array";
            foreach($value as $sub => $value2){
                echo "Sub: ".$sub." / ".$value2." <br/>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Content: ".$key." / ".$value." <br/>";
        }
}
```

But this do not work. What I miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublog is an array of arrays. You can create a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) function that will print all the values:

```
$array = json_decode($casedata,true);

printKeyValues($array);

function printKeyValues($input) {
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            printKeyValues($value);
        } else {
            echo "Content: ".$key." / ".$value. <br/>;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You inner array is a 1D array and not an associative array.

Try using

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo "Array";
            $count = count($value);
            for($i=0;i<$count;i++) {
                echo $value[i]['step']; // <---
             }
        }
    }else{
        echo "Content: ".$key." / ".$value." <br/>";
    }
}
```